# Android: Download file from password protected website

Tags: java, android, urlconnection

I need to download some pdf files from a site where users have to login before they can download any files.

If a user is not logged into the site, links to pdf files will redirect to the login page.

I managed to post user credentials to the login page and save the cookie from the response and I tried providing that cookie to the `URLConnection` when attempting download, but I am still getting the login page instead of my pdf file.

**UPDATE:** code added.

**Posting user credentials:**

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write("username=" + username + "&password=" + password);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();

String result = HttpUtils.getResponseString(conn);
if (result.indexOf("Invalid") == -1) {
    String cookie = conn.getHeaderField("set-cookie");
    return cookie;
}
```

**cookie is then stored and used in the following code segment**

**Attempting to download the pdf :**

```
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", _cookie);
conn.connect();
InputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 1024);
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(_pdfFile);
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
int count = 0;
while ((count = inStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
    outStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
inStream.close();
```

Comment: Try debugging this download flow through `curl` from the command-line.

Comment: @LinX64 I added the codes but couldn't make the formatting right.

Comment: no problem, just use {} in the editor, i did it btw.

Comment: Sniff the HTTP traffic while you do the download in a browser. I bet you're either forgetting to pass a cookie back in the subsequent request or you're missing it after the login succeeds. Or you're missing a redirect or something that results in a cookie being set after successful login.

Comment: @JimW I sniffed the traffic as you suggested. The login page returns two cookies (one of them is "deleted" which is probably is not sent to the java code), No redirects also.